# how to correctly remove a restarted branch (the original bit) for bitbucket synchronization?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

**Summary**: how to synchronize bitbucket with my local repo after having stripped a changeset locally from a branch which has been restarted?

**Details**:

My code in Mercurial has a `default` branch with the stable version. I create named branches to do some tests, eventually merging them into `default` if the changes are fine.

I created at some point a short-lived `extratemp` branch (one commit) which I abandoned. Later on I recreated a new branch also named `extratemp`. When committing, Tortoise Hg asked me if I wanted to "restart" the branch and I said yes (which was probably a bad idea).

I then decided to `strip` the old, short-lived, extratemp branch with `hg strip -r 126` (where `126` was the short-lived changeset). So far so good, I now have the following view of the branches:

[image]

I then pushed to bitbucket and since it was reluctant :) I did a `hg push --new-branch --force`. Its view of the commits is the following:

[image]

As you can see it retained the bit I stripped (commit `5ac3e1b`). If I now pull I get it back:

[image]

What can I do to force bitbucket to be synchronized with my local repo so that the original `extratemp` is not retained?

Comment: By the way, you should never force anything. If you need to force something, there is probably something wrong with your repo, and you should fix it before pushing. In this case, your push created 2 heads.

Comment: When I mentionned that bitbucket was reluctant to accept my push I knew that forcing a push was probably not a good idea. I was expecting the `--force` would be similar to `hg update -C` in the sense that it would discard the remote bits which are different from the local ones. I should have RTFM with understanding, though :). Thanks for your answer, it brought the tree to a correct state.

Comment: Fair enough! IMHO, it is always preferable to keep the changeset anyway, and render it inactive, than to remove it from the history. It is another way of keeping tabs on the work done or even attempted.

Comment: I agree and usually close the branches which led to nothing (to, as you mentioned, keep history and not retry something a year later - this is what I did with the `kivy` one afterwards). The mistake I did here was to reuse the name of an existing branch and accepting it to be "restarted". I should have closed it and chosen a new name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strip cannot be synchronized, since it is the absence of a changeset. The original commit has been made public already, and it exists everywhere it has been pulled. Even if you remove it from the main repo, it may get pushed back again by another, eventually. If you want to remove it from the other repositories, you will have to strip it manually everywhere.

While this may be possible if the repo is private and if you control who has access to it, it can be harder for public repos. The best alternative is to leave the changeset while rendering it *inactive*.

To do so, simply merge the two heads of `extratemp` on your local repo, by following these [instructions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge) to the letter. Then, your branch should only have one head, with your current state.